# how to print black charaters ascii in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, character-encoding, ascii-art

I would like to print an ascii in a batch file... I tried using this code:

```
    @echo off
>%temp%\temp.txt (
echo                                                                   
echo ███ ▀▄    ▄     ██      ▄   ████▄    ▄    ▄  █ ▄███▄      ▄  ████▄ 
echo █  █  █  █      █ █      █  █   █     █  █   █ █▀   ▀ ▀▄   █ █   █ 
echo █ ▀ ▄  ▀█       █▄▄█ ██   █ █   █ ██   █ ██▀▀█ ██▄▄     █ ▀  █   █ 
echo █  ▄▀  █        █  █ █ █  █ ▀████ █ █  █ █   █ █▄   ▄▀ ▄ █   ▀████ 
echo ███  ▄▀            █ █  █ █       █  █ █    █  ▀███▀  █   ▀▄       
echo                   █  █   ██       █   ██   ▀           ▀           
echo                  ▀                                                
)
type %temp%\temp.txt
timeout 1 >nul
del %temp%\temp.txt
pause >nul
```

but I get this in output:

```
ECHO diattivato.
ÔûêÔûêÔûê ÔûÇÔûä    Ôûä     ÔûêÔûê      Ôûä   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûä    Ôûä    Ôûä  Ôûê ÔûäÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûä      Ôûä  ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûä
Ôûê  Ôûê  Ôûê  Ôûê      Ôûê Ôûê      Ôûê  Ôûê   Ôûê     Ôûê  Ôûê   Ôûê ÔûêÔûÇ   ÔûÇ ÔûÇÔûä   Ôûê Ôûê   Ôûê
Ôûê ÔûÇ Ôûä  ÔûÇÔûê       ÔûêÔûäÔûäÔûê ÔûêÔûê   Ôûê Ôûê   Ôûê ÔûêÔûê   Ôûê ÔûêÔûêÔûÇÔûÇÔûê ÔûêÔûêÔûäÔûä     Ôûê ÔûÇ  Ôûê   Ôûê
Ôûê  ÔûäÔûÇ  Ôûê        Ôûê  Ôûê Ôûê Ôûê  Ôûê ÔûÇÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê Ôûê Ôûê  Ôûê Ôûê   Ôûê ÔûêÔûä   ÔûäÔûÇ Ôûä Ôûê   ÔûÇÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê
ÔûêÔûêÔûê  ÔûäÔûÇ            Ôûê Ôûê  Ôûê Ôûê       Ôûê  Ôûê Ôûê    Ôûê  ÔûÇÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûÇ  Ôûê   ÔûÇÔûä
                  Ôûê  Ôûê   ÔûêÔûê       Ôûê   ÔûêÔûê   ÔûÇ           ÔûÇ
                 ÔûÇ
```

I also tried to escape character whit this caracher before the text "^" but it's always the same...
Can someone help me fix this problem? 
I didn't find any other duplicateds of this question so I asked here...
.

Thanks, and have a good day.

Comment: in the output " ECHO disattivato " is the italian output of the command " echo off " btw...

Comment: put `chcp 65001 >nul` before the `echo` lines and use `echo/` to echo an empty line (without a space)

Comment: @Sephan, i get this: 
`Formato del parametro non corretto - echo` 
few times...
It means: Format parameter not valid - echo

Comment: What does `chcp` return when being typed in a Command Prompt window? And what is the encoding of the batch file (open/edit the file in Notepad, then go to "File » Save As…" to find out)?

Comment: @aschipfl when typed in cmd it return this: `Tabella codici attiva: 850` (Active table code: 850)
The encoding is UTF-8

Comment: @T3RR0R, `echo/` (as already suggested by Stephan) is better than `echo.` as this might fail when there is a file named `echo` (no extension) in the current directory, and `echo/` is also faster as the file system is not accessed...

Comment: fair point, I do recall having seen the failure when echo file exists explained somewhere previously - wasn't aware of the performance benefit however. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: It seems that the temporary file `%temp%\temp.txt` receives the correct text, independent on the current code page (it worked for me with `chcp 437`, `chcp 850`, `chcp 1252` and `chcp 65001`). But I failed in displaying the text (with `type`), even when changing the code page (again) after the `echo` block.

Comment: @aschipfl there's other  ways to print out the content of temp.txt or other ways to just only print this ascii art?

Comment: I also thought of that but unfortunately had no luck so far...

Comment: `echo ±²³` in notepad prints `▒▓│`. Enter the code in notepad ALT+0177 which shows ANSI `±` and prints as OEM `▒`. Note: The leading zero is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Command Processor and batch files exist since quite some time long before UTF-8 encoding was introduced, so the support is far beyond granted.

Anyway, I finally found a way to display the text correctly – here it is:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Store current code page in a variable for later restore (optional):
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%C in ('chcp') do set /A "$CP=%%C"
rem // Change code page to UTF-8 Unicode:
chcp 65001 > nul
rem // Write text into temporary file:
> "%TEMP%\temp.txt" (
    echo/                                                                   
    echo ███ ▀▄    ▄     ██      ▄   ████▄    ▄    ▄  █ ▄███▄      ▄  ████▄ 
    echo █  █  █  █      █ █      █  █   █     █  █   █ █▀   ▀ ▀▄   █ █   █ 
    echo █ ▀ ▄  ▀█       █▄▄█ ██   █ █   █ ██   █ ██▀▀█ ██▄▄     █ ▀  █   █ 
    echo █  ▄▀  █        █  █ █ █  █ ▀████ █ █  █ █   █ █▄   ▄▀ ▄ █   ▀████ 
    echo ███  ▄▀            █ █  █ █       █  █ █    █  ▀███▀  █   ▀▄       
    echo                   █  █   ██       █   ██   ▀           ▀           
    echo                  ▀                                                 
)
rem /* Open a new instance of the Command Processor; inside this,
rem    change code page to original IBM PC and type out the temporary file: */
cmd /C chcp 437 ^> nul ^& type "%TEMP%\temp.txt"
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%TEMP%\temp.txt"
rem // Restore original code page (optional):
chcp %$CP% > nul
```

Note that I tested it on a 64-bit Windows 7 (SP1) machine.

---

This is an alternative way that does not require a temporary file:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Store current code page in a variable for later restore (optional):
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%C in ('chcp') do set /A "$CP=%%C"
rem // Change code page to UTF-8 Unicode:
chcp 65001 > nul
rem // Provide text in pseudo-comments (invalid labels):
::::                                                                    
:::: ███ ▀▄    ▄     ██      ▄   ████▄    ▄    ▄  █ ▄███▄      ▄  ████▄ 
:::: █  █  █  █      █ █      █  █   █     █  █   █ █▀   ▀ ▀▄   █ █   █ 
:::: █ ▀ ▄  ▀█       █▄▄█ ██   █ █   █ ██   █ ██▀▀█ ██▄▄     █ ▀  █   █ 
:::: █  ▄▀  █        █  █ █ █  █ ▀████ █ █  █ █   █ █▄   ▄▀ ▄ █   ▀████ 
:::: ███  ▄▀            █ █  █ █       █  █ █    █  ▀███▀  █   ▀▄       
::::                   █  █   ██       █   ██   ▀           ▀           
::::                  ▀                                                 
rem /* Instantiate a `for /F` loop, which opens a new Command Processor instance;
rem    inside this, change code page to original IBM PC, use `findstr` to extract
rem    all lines from this batch file that begin with `::::` and print them with
rem    the `::::` prefix removed: */
for /F "delims=:" %%T in ('chcp 437 ^> nul ^& findstr "^::::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%T
rem // Restore original code page (optional):
chcp %$CP% > nul
```

---

I have to admit that I sadly do not (yet) have an idea why another instance of `cmd` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

`Echo ±²³` in notepad prints `▒▓│`. Enter the code in notepad RIGHT_ALT+0177 which shows ANSI `±` and prints as OEM `▒`. Note: The leading zero is important.

Alt+177 will enter a ANSI/Unicode conversion
 of the OEM character 177 which is Unicode 9618 in Unicode apps like notepad and code 166 in an ANSI app while Alt+0177 will enter the ANSI character 177.

You could also use Unicode. `chcp 65001` turns on UTF8 mode and 9618 will display correctly.

This is the character chart showing what code to enter in notepad (ANSI) and what you'll see in CMD (OEM). 
Most codepoints 0-31 require a special console mode to display characters.

```
        Name    OEM Type    Range   (Unicode conversion of OEM Character)
0   0x0 ␀       Control     Control Codes
1   0x1 ␁   ☺   Control     Control Codes
2   0x2 ␂   ☻   Control     Control Codes
3   0x3 ␃   ♥   Control     Control Codes
4   0x4 ␄   ♦   Control     Control Codes
5   0x5 ␅   ♣   Control     Control Codes
6   0x6 ␆   ♠   Control     Control Codes
7   0x7 ␇   •   Control     Control Codes
8   0x8 ␈   ◘   Control     Control Codes
9   0x9 ␉   ○   Blank Control Space     Control Codes
10  0xA ␊   ◙   Control Space   Control Codes
11  0xB ␋   ♂   Control Space   Control Codes
12  0xC ␌   ♀   Control Space   Control Codes
13  0xD ␍   ♪   Control Space   Control Codes
14  0xE ␎   ♫   Control     Control Codes
15  0xF ␏   ☼   Control     Control Codes
16  0x10    ␐   ►   Control     Control Codes
17  0x11    ␑   ◄   Control     Control Codes
18  0x12    ␒   ↕   Control     Control Codes
19  0x13    ␓   ‼   Control     Control Codes
20  0x14    ␔   ¶   Control     Control Codes
21  0x15    ␕   §   Control     Control Codes
22  0x16    ␖   ▬   Control     Control Codes
23  0x17    ␗   ↨   Control     Control Codes
24  0x18    ␘   ↑   Control     Control Codes
25  0x19    ␙   ↓   Control     Control Codes
26  0x1A    ␚   →   Control     Control Codes
27  0x1B    ␛   ←   Control     Control Codes
28  0x1C    ␜   ∟   Control     Control Codes
29  0x1D    ␝   ↔   Control     Control Codes
30  0x1E    ␞   ▲   Control     Control Codes
31  0x1F    ␟   ▼   Control     Control Codes

        Char    Type    Range
32  0x20        Blank Space     Basic Latin
33  0x21    !   Punct   Basic Latin
34  0x22    "   Punct   Basic Latin
35  0x23    #   Punct   Basic Latin
36  0x24    $   Punct   Basic Latin
37  0x25    %   Punct   Basic Latin
38  0x26    &   Punct   Basic Latin
39  0x27    '   Punct   Basic Latin
40  0x28    (   Punct   Basic Latin
41  0x29    )   Punct   Basic Latin
42  0x2A    *   Punct   Basic Latin
43  0x2B    +   Punct   Basic Latin
44  0x2C    ,   Punct   Basic Latin
45  0x2D    -   Punct   Basic Latin
46  0x2E    .   Punct   Basic Latin
47  0x2F    /   Punct   Basic Latin
48  0x30    0   Number Hex  Basic Latin
49  0x31    1   Number Hex  Basic Latin
50  0x32    2   Number Hex  Basic Latin
51  0x33    3   Number Hex  Basic Latin
52  0x34    4   Number Hex  Basic Latin
53  0x35    5   Number Hex  Basic Latin
54  0x36    6   Number Hex  Basic Latin
55  0x37    7   Number Hex  Basic Latin
56  0x38    8   Number Hex  Basic Latin
57  0x39    9   Number Hex  Basic Latin
58  0x3A    :   Punct   Basic Latin
59  0x3B    ;   Punct   Basic Latin
60  0x3C    <   Punct   Basic Latin
61  0x3D    =   Punct   Basic Latin
62  0x3E    >   Punct   Basic Latin
63  0x3F    ?   Punct   Basic Latin
64  0x40    @   Punct   Basic Latin
65  0x41    A   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
66  0x42    B   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
67  0x43    C   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
68  0x44    D   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
69  0x45    E   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
70  0x46    F   Alpha Upper Hex     Basic Latin
71  0x47    G   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
72  0x48    H   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
73  0x49    I   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
74  0x4A    J   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
75  0x4B    K   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
76  0x4C    L   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
77  0x4D    M   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
78  0x4E    N   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
79  0x4F    O   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
80  0x50    P   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
81  0x51    Q   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
82  0x52    R   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
83  0x53    S   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
84  0x54    T   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
85  0x55    U   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
86  0x56    V   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
87  0x57    W   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
88  0x58    X   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
89  0x59    Y   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
90  0x5A    Z   Alpha Upper     Basic Latin
91  0x5B    [   Punct   Basic Latin
92  0x5C    \   Punct   Basic Latin
93  0x5D    ]   Punct   Basic Latin
94  0x5E    ^   Punct   Basic Latin
95  0x5F    _   Punct   Basic Latin
96  0x60    `   Punct   Basic Latin
97  0x61    a   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
98  0x62    b   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
99  0x63    c   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
100 0x64    d   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
101 0x65    e   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
102 0x66    f   Alpha Lower Hex     Basic Latin
103 0x67    g   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
104 0x68    h   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
105 0x69    i   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
106 0x6A    j   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
107 0x6B    k   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
108 0x6C    l   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
109 0x6D    m   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
110 0x6E    n   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
111 0x6F    o   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
112 0x70    p   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
113 0x71    q   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
114 0x72    r   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
115 0x73    s   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
116 0x74    t   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
117 0x75    u   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
118 0x76    v   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
119 0x77    w   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
120 0x78    x   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
121 0x79    y   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
122 0x7A    z   Alpha Lower     Basic Latin
123 0x7B    {   Punct   Basic Latin
124 0x7C    |   Punct   Basic Latin
125 0x7D    }   Punct   Basic Latin
126 0x7E    ~   Punct   Basic Latin
127 0x7F        Control     Basic Latin

        UTF ANSI    OEM Type    Range   (ANSI conversion of OEM Character eg ® replaced by R)
128 0x80    €   €   ¼   Control     Control Codes
129 0x81            ü   Control     Control Codes
130 0x82    ‚   ‚   →   Control     Control Codes
131 0x83    ƒ   ƒ   Æ   Control     Control Codes
132 0x84    „   „   ▲   Control     Control Codes
133 0x85    …   …   &   Control Space   Control Codes
134 0x86    †   †       Control     Control Codes
135 0x87    ‡   ‡   !   Control     Control Codes
136 0x88    ˆ   ˆ   ã   Control     Control Codes
137 0x89    ‰   ‰   0   Control     Control Codes
138 0x8A    Š   Š   `   Control     Control Codes
139 0x8B    ‹   ‹   9   Control     Control Codes
140 0x8C    Œ   Œ   R   Control     Control Codes
141 0x8D            ì   Control     Control Codes
142 0x8E    Ž   Ž   }   Control     Control Codes
143 0x8F            Å   Control     Control Codes
144 0x90            É   Control     Control Codes
145 0x91    ‘   ‘   ↑   Control     Control Codes
146 0x92    ’   ’   ↓   Control     Control Codes
147 0x93    “   “   ∟   Control     Control Codes
148 0x94    ”   ”   ↔   Control     Control Codes
149 0x95    •   •   "   Control     Control Codes
150 0x96    –   –   ‼   Control     Control Codes
151 0x97    —   —   ¶   Control     Control Codes
152 0x98    ˜   ˜   ▄   Control     Control Codes
153 0x99    ™   ™   "   Control     Control Codes
154 0x9A    š   š   a   Control     Control Codes
155 0x9B    ›   ›   :   Control     Control Codes
156 0x9C    œ   œ   S   Control     Control Codes
157 0x9D            Ø   Control     Control Codes
158 0x9E    ž   ž   ~   Control     Control Codes
159 0x9F    Ÿ   Ÿ   x   Control     Control Codes
160 0xA0            á   Blank Space     Latin-1 Supplement
161 0xA1    ¡   ¡   í   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
162 0xA2    ¢   ¢   ó   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
163 0xA3    £   £   ú   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
164 0xA4    ¤   ¤   ñ   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
165 0xA5    ¥   ¥   Ñ   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
166 0xA6    ¦   ¦   ª   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
167 0xA7    §   §   º   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
168 0xA8    ¨   ¨   ¿   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
169 0xA9    ©   ©   ®   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
170 0xAA    ª   ª   ¬   Alpha Lower Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
171 0xAB    «   «   ½   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
172 0xAC    ¬   ¬   ¼   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
173 0xAD    ­   ­   ¡   Control Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
174 0xAE    ®   ®   «   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
175 0xAF    ¯   ¯   »   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
176 0xB0    °   °   ░   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
177 0xB1    ±   ±   ▒   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
178 0xB2    ²   ²   ▓   Number Punct    Latin-1 Supplement
179 0xB3    ³   ³   │   Number Punct    Latin-1 Supplement
180 0xB4    ´   ´   ┤   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
181 0xB5    µ   µ   Á   Alpha Lower Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
182 0xB6    ¶   ¶   Â   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
183 0xB7    ·   ·   À   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
184 0xB8    ¸   ¸   ©   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
185 0xB9    ¹   ¹   ╣   Number Punct    Latin-1 Supplement
186 0xBA    º   º   ║   Alpha Lower Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
187 0xBB    »   »   ╗   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
188 0xBC    ¼   ¼   ╝   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
189 0xBD    ½   ½   ¢   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
190 0xBE    ¾   ¾   ¥   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
191 0xBF    ¿   ¿   ┐   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
192 0xC0    À   À   └   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
193 0xC1    Á   Á   ┴   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
194 0xC2    Â   Â   ┬   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
195 0xC3    Ã   Ã   ├   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
196 0xC4    Ä   Ä   ─   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
197 0xC5    Å   Å   ┼   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
198 0xC6    Æ   Æ   ã   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
199 0xC7    Ç   Ç   Ã   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
200 0xC8    È   È   ╚   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
201 0xC9    É   É   ╔   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
202 0xCA    Ê   Ê   ╩   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
203 0xCB    Ë   Ë   ╦   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
204 0xCC    Ì   Ì   ╠   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
205 0xCD    Í   Í   ═   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
206 0xCE    Î   Î   ╬   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
207 0xCF    Ï   Ï   ¤   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
208 0xD0    Ð   Ð   ð   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
209 0xD1    Ñ   Ñ   Ð   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
210 0xD2    Ò   Ò   Ê   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
211 0xD3    Ó   Ó   Ë   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
212 0xD4    Ô   Ô   È   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
213 0xD5    Õ   Õ   ı   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
214 0xD6    Ö   Ö   Í   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
215 0xD7    ×   ×   Î   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
216 0xD8    Ø   Ø   Ï   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
217 0xD9    Ù   Ù   ┘   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
218 0xDA    Ú   Ú   ┌   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
219 0xDB    Û   Û   █   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
220 0xDC    Ü   Ü   ▄   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
221 0xDD    Ý   Ý   ¦   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
222 0xDE    Þ   Þ   Ì   Alpha Upper     Latin-1 Supplement
223 0xDF    ß   ß   ▀   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
224 0xE0    à   à   Ó   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
225 0xE1    á   á   ß   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
226 0xE2    â   â   Ô   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
227 0xE3    ã   ã   Ò   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
228 0xE4    ä   ä   õ   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
229 0xE5    å   å   Õ   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
230 0xE6    æ   æ   µ   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
231 0xE7    ç   ç   þ   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
232 0xE8    è   è   Þ   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
233 0xE9    é   é   Ú   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
234 0xEA    ê   ê   Û   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
235 0xEB    ë   ë   Ù   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
236 0xEC    ì   ì   ý   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
237 0xED    í   í   Ý   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
238 0xEE    î   î   ¯   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
239 0xEF    ï   ï   ´   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
240 0xF0    ð   ð   ­   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
241 0xF1    ñ   ñ   ±   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
242 0xF2    ò   ò   ‗   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
243 0xF3    ó   ó   ¾   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
244 0xF4    ô   ô   ¶   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
245 0xF5    õ   õ   §   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
246 0xF6    ö   ö   ÷   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
247 0xF7    ÷   ÷   ¸   Punct   Latin-1 Supplement
248 0xF8    ø   ø   °   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
249 0xF9    ù   ù   ¨   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
250 0xFA    ú   ú   ·   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
251 0xFB    û   û   ¹   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
252 0xFC    ü   ü   ³   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
253 0xFD    ý   ý   ²   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
254 0xFE    þ   þ   ■   Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
255 0xFF    ÿ   ÿ       Alpha Lower     Latin-1 Supplement
```

I posted this table on my repository https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/character-table-oem-ansi-and-unicode.html